# Check if element exist in arrays object of array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I have one array like this.

```
var MembersArray = [
    {
        id: [1,2],
        name: ['Arjun', 'Parth'],
    },
    {
        id: [2,5],
        name: ['Arjun', 'Rahul']
    },
    {
        id: [3,6],
        name: ['Chetan', 'kumar']
    }
];
```

I want to find if id **2** exist in `MembersArray`, Normally if the array is like [1,2,3] this, then we can use **array.some()** method but I don't know how to check if the `id` exists in this array or not.

Comment: You can nest another array method like some, includes or find and iterate over ids

Comment: can you give me example for the same

Comment: Inside your **some** method you have single object. You need to access that object's id property and use for example includes method: `object.id.includes(2)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const id = 2;
const isIdInArray = MembersArray.some(item => item.id.includes(id));
```

Now you have constant **isIdInArray** which is type of boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` for getting the required result.

```js
var MembersArray = [
    {
        id: [1,2],
        name: ['Arjun', 'Parth'],
    },
    {
        id: [2,5],
        name: ['Arjun', 'Rahul']
    },
    {
        id: [3,6],
        name: ['Chetan', 'kumar']
    }
];

const res = MembersArray.filter(({id}) => id.indexOf(2) > -1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solutions

```
     <script>
      var MembersArray = [
        {
          id: [1, 2],
          name: ['Arjun', 'Parth']
        },
        {
          id: [2, 5],
          name: ['Arjun', 'Rahul']
        },
        {
          id: [3, 6],
          name: ['Chetan', 'kumar']
        }
      ];
      var checkMemberId = 2;

      function fn_checkMemberId(_checkMemberId, _membersArray) {
        let _memberExist = false;

        for (i = 0; i < _membersArray.length; i++) {
          if (_membersArray[i]['id'].includes(_checkMemberId)) {
            _memberExist = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        return _memberExist;
      }

      let memberExistResult = fn_checkMemberId(checkMemberId, MembersArray);
      console.log(`Member ${checkMemberId} exist: ${memberExistResult}`);
    </script>
```